# calendar plugin that works inside cluetip

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, cluetip

Is there any calendar that works inside the cluetip i have used jquery ui calendar and many other calendar they work very fine out side the cluetip but when ever it call inside the cluetip it dint work

Please help thanx in advance

```
<div class="calendar_button"> <a class="cal_box" href="#calendar" rel="#calendar">
        <div class="calendar_side_buton_icon"></div>
        <span>Calendar</span> </a> </div>
      <!-- close photo button -->

      <div class="displaynone" id="calendar">
        <div class="modalbox_header">
          <div class="modalbox_header_icon calen_icon"></div>
          <div class="modalbox_header_txt">Calendar</div>
        </div>
        <!-- close modalbox header -->
        <div class="modalbox_content">
          <div class="cal_container">
            <div class="cal_view">
            <div id="datepicker"></div>
              <div class="caln_header">
                <div class="caln_header_left"></div>
                <div class="caln_header_center">
                  <div class="left_keyring"></div>
                  <div class="right_keyring"></div>
```

check i have so many divs.

Comment: It seems to me that jQuery UI Datepicker works OK. See for yourself: http://jsbin.com/owaset/1

Comment: its just hovering but not able to click on calendar

Comment: use sticky:true u will be able to stop the datepicker but that will not work check this http://jsbin.com/owaset/3/edit

Comment: True, but just, because I made it that way. See after little edit: http://jsbin.com/owaset/5

Comment: i know it selects the date but the problem in changing month.which is the actuall problem i am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As now I know your problem, I came with (a bit hacky) solution. You can see it [here](http://jsbin.com/owaset/7):

```
$('.cluetip-trigger').cluetip({
  local: true,
  showTitle: false,
  width: '305px',
  sticky: true,
  onShow: function(ct, ci){
    this.calendar = $('<div>').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        alert('You\'ve selected '+dateText);
      }
    }).appendTo(ci);
  },
  onHide: function(ct, ci){
      this.calendar.datepicker( "destroy" ).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('a.cal_box').cluetip({local:true, hideLocal: true ,onShow: function(ct, ci){
    this.calendar = $('<div>').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        alert('You\'ve selected '+dateText);
      }
    }).appendTo(ci);
  },
  onHide: function(ct, ci){
      this.calendar.datepicker( "destroy" ).remove();
  }, sticky: true, arrows: true, cursor: 'pointer',width:970, height:530}); `

dint worked for me

Comment: Here's your code (second link) in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/owaset/8 and (at least in my browser) it works...

Comment: please check my question i have so many divs inside and the releation of cluetip with calendar id

`<a class="cal_box" href="#calendar" rel="#calendar">`

but i have to display inside datepicker id

`<div id="datepicker"></div>`

and i can not chane the relation to datepicker as there are too many stuff connected to it.

i appreciate you help please and thanx in advace

Comment: but you th life saver :)